# How can I change background color for the desktop?

Tags: gnome, desktop-background

Recently (after updating to 13.10) I started experiencing this problem. I have a number of background photographs that change with 5-minute interval, set to stretch. However, the colour of the rest of the desktop, not covered by the picture, is in contrasting color. I would like to change it to black.

How can I do that?

[image: screenshot of a desctop]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by going to `Settings/Background` and selecting a the desired solid color (`black` in this case), then select one more time the image desired.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via Wallch!

Wallch allows you not only to change it to a solid color, but also to change it to the "average" color of the picture.

Pic for reference:[image]

You can install it via the unstable PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wallch/3+
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wallch
```

Comment: That's one cool program

Comment: It's because of the developers being cool (hint: I am one of them :P)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on desktop, *Change Desktop Background* and there select another color. :)

Comment: I do not have that in context menu on the right-click. And in Settings/background i am only offered to set solid color instead of my picture slideshow

Comment: @Srv19 please select the black solid color, and then set the image one more time, and tell us what happen.

Comment: @Srv19 That is interesting. In my settings dialog there is a color picker under the little monitor in which the preview is shown. And I can change it to any color, and if the wallpaper doesn't fill the screen that color will be shown.

Comment: @Srv19 Oh I see you don't use unity, then what do you use? Okay I see the pic, gnome3.

Comment: @falconer: you are right

Comment: @Hans: i did what you advised and was rewarded with the result i wanted to see. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the dash and type in `Appearance` You will be prompt with the current background image and below the display image there is a little blue square, select it and select the background color that You want (`Black` in this case).

If you have any other question please let us know.

Comment: Don't have unity; no dash, no Appearance.